# UIPanGesture selector method is not called in iPhone sdk(iOS 5.1)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, uigesturerecognizer

I am trying to use UIPanGesture to one of my view. Unfortunately the selector method for that UIPanGesture is not triggering.

Here my code:

```
 UIPanGestureRecognizer * panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTransactionPan:)];
    [self.graphView addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
```

This is my selector method:

```
-(void)handleTransactionPan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)recognizer 
{
    NSLog(@"\n Inside Pan Gesture.....");
}
```

Friends pls suggest me with ur ideas wt's wrong I did here.

Thanks to all,
Monish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this
`UIPanGestureRecognizer * panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTransactionPan:)];
    [self.graphView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [self.graphView addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];`